# Regex expression for redirecting image URLs to another folder

Tags: images, redirect, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, regex

I have changed the upload folder to a folder called "images" in the root folder by entering `define('UPLOADS', 'images');` inside wp-config.php file. My Media settings had the images organized into month and year. I changed that not to use any date organization. I want to be able to redirect all previous image URLs that were in the form of `siteroot/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/image.png` to point to the new folder, like this `siteroot/images/image.png`. Not all images are PNGs, of course, I would need that to happen for every file inside the previous upload folder and subfolders! I can copy all existing individual images and other files into the **images** root folder but I am not sure how to set up the redirection. Yoast Premium has a redirection module that can accept regular expressions.

Can anyone suggest a regex that will work?

Comment: You could use .htaccess by adding RewriteRule ^/wp-content/uploads/2020/$ http://www.yourdomain.com/images/ [R=301,L] - The 301 tells visitors & bots the URL has moved permanently. This assumes your server config allows rewrites. Another option would be a rewrite rule within your Apache or Nginx server config, depending on what http server you are using.

Comment: The server accepts rewrites. I am testing on staging site. I am trying to redirect an image in the form of `https://stage.sitename/2020/02/image.jpg` to go to `https://stage.sitename/images/image.jpg`. I use this expression inside the .htaccess file:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage.sitename\.com$ [OR]`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.stage.sitename\.com$`
`RewriteRule \/wp-content\/uploads\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/(.*).(?:jpg|gif|png)$ "https\:\/\/www\.stage.sitename\.com\/images$1" [R=301,L]`

But it doesn't seem to work.